# Text area to modify HTML - rendering line breaks

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea, line-breaks

I'm loading a portion of an HTML page into a text area so that I can make small changes.  All the HTML tags are shown along with the text, which is what I need to happen; I don't want a WYSIWYG editor or anything fancy.

The one thing I want is for line breaks to be shown in the text area in addition to the `<p></p>` and `<h1></h1>` tags otherwise it's a giant wall of text and it's really hard to proof read.  I don't want the line breaks to be doubled after I save the modifications though as the next step will be to convert everything in the text area to a PDF file.

ETA: nl2br() doesn't work because there are no line breaks to begin with.  The content is assembled from paragraphs in a MySQL database using a loop.  The

tags are inserted during the loop too.

What's the best way to do this?  I'm using PHP.

Oh, PS - I'm aware of the security concerns of not stripping the tags.  This page is for the admin (me) only and will be password protected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can filter those first, before showing to `textarea`? Something like this, maybe (add newline after the closing tag):

```
$rawhtml = str_replace(array("</p>", "</h1>"), "\n", $rawhtml);
```

Comment: Of course!  I had tried that, but a syntax error threw me off.  Do I need to strip the "\n\n" before saving the final draft or no?  
Thanks!  Billy

Comment: that depends. Do you want ot to be cleared again on your database or not?

Answer (score 0):

Before sending data to your textarea put your variable in nl2br() func then send it to your textarea.

Comment: This doesn't work because there are no line breaks to begin with.  The content is assembled from paragraphs in a mySQL database using a loop.  The <p> tags are inserted during the loop too.  I'm sorry; i guess I should have included that in the original post!  
Thanks,  
Billy